# How do I receive the updated time every time it is called in this function?

Tags: python, time

```
    import time
    seconds = time.time()
    local_time = time.ctime(seconds)
    print("Start Time:", local_time)
    def bot():
        x = 0
        while x < 16:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Time:", local_time)
            x += 1
```

When I run this code it prints the initial time take before the function every time, I would like it to show the updated time every time local time is printed, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Regarding the downvotes - It sometimes helps to explain what you've tried to solve the problem on your own, rather than only describe the issue

Comment: I see... thanks for the input. Will try to make a better post next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a variable will not re-evaluate it. You'll need to calculate the time again each loop iteration

```
import time
    
def bot():
    for x in range(16):
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds = time.time()
        local_time = time.ctime(seconds)
        print("Time:", local_time)

bot()
```

Comment: This worked pretty well.. Can i ask one more question? If I wanted to calculate the time again in the same function right after I calculated it the first time, is that possible? Simply adding this line "print("Time:", local_time)" doesn't work, as a new time isn't generated until the x value increases.

Comment: Again, you'll need to reassign the variable.